# Depreciation Problem

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I am hoping that you can all assist, for which I would be grateful

so we have a bolt & it's worth $100

This bolt has a 40 year in service life based on its required usage (we will only need it for forty years - not a single one but access to this particular type of bolt

It is used by 5 platforms which came into life in different years, and go out of life in different years

eg

1 - 2000 - 2020 (20 year life)

2 - 2001 - 2025 (24 year life)

3 - 2004 - 2030 (26 year life)

4 - 2004 - 2035 (31 year life)

5 - 2006 - 2040 (34 year life)

Each of the 5 platforms has a start date (in service date) and an end date ( out of service date)

They all use this specific bolt

It's life based on those 5 platforms that use it is the year range 2000 - 2040 (so 40 years)

So as a single unit it has a 40 year depreciation cost ( we use the straight line method)

The bolt in this example is $100 per bolt ($100 depreciating in value each year to $0 - no scrap value)

The problem

I am trying to figure out based on the stock held against each platform how to work out total stock depreciation opposed to that of 1 bolt. If held on the shelf.

So random numbers here but lets say each of the platforms use each year

1 - 1 Bolts

2 - 2 Bolts

3 - 3 Bolts

4 - 4 Bolts

5 - 5 Bolts

1 - 1 Bolts x 20 = 20 Bolts

2 - 2 Bolts x 24 = 48 Bolts

3 - 3 Bolts x 26 = 78 Bolts

4 - 4 Bolts x 31 = 124 Bolts

5 - 5 Bolts x 34 = 170 Bolts

In the current window we have 440 bolts used over 40 years.

For 1 bolt the deprecation is $100 over 40 years

for 440 it is (440*100)/40 years

I think?????

But I am trying to work out the value of each platform as a percentage of the whole

Soooo the percentage of the deprecation of the whole

I think

1 - ( 20 Bolts * $100) / 20 Years

2 - (24 = 48 Bolts * $100) / 24 years

3 - (78 Bolts * $100) / 26 years

4 - (124 Bolts * $100) / 31 years

5 - (170 Bolts * $100) / 34 years

Because surely although they all use the bolt they contribute differently to its overall deprecation. Based on the quantity of that bolt which they uniquely consume

SO

If Platform 4 Extended its life and usage by a further 3 years.. It would use a further 93 bolts. Making its depreciation

4- (217 Bolts * $100) / 34 Years

Completely changing its percentage of the usage of the bolt and its subsequent depreciation?

The end goal is to work out how much Each platform shares the depreciation.

Then with each platform coming to its end of life what the new depreciation figure would look like.

Is this something that is possible to determine in excel?

Using
Platform

In Service day/month/year (to get days)
Out of service day/month/year

Initial purchase value of product

end value of product

Taking the earliest date of the platforms in the list as the beginning

and the end service date from the longest in service platform

In order to argue accurately costing out the monies saved by purchasing the correct amount of bolts to cover the life of each individual platform and not hold surplus at any point in the chain

The proof I am looking for is to demonstrate don't buy more milk than you can drink before it expires.

As once its expired it was a waste a money

In this case.

If we buy too many bolts, all those that we don't use which we will have paid full price for, and they will depreciate to the final day of the final platform without every being consumed. Costing money unnecessarily. But if we buy the exact amount required for each platform to cover it's life (each year the price of the bolt may change - up or down) then we won't be wasting money buying an asset that we will never use.

Comment: Oh my god how long is this problem! Can you summarise what you want and what you are given / known? No one is going to read all this...

Comment: Well I hope at least one person will. 

I need to adjust the total deprecation value of 'x' as a £/$ figure of total quantity, considering quantities of 'x' are either added or removed through the life of 'x'.

Comment: I suggest your company hire a mathematical consultant. It sounds like the problem should be worth it to you. [recreational-mathematics? really?]

Comment: I wish they would. Currently I am trying to demonstrate that it is in their interest. Without any demonstrable proof other than an assumption that this would save money in the long run. I am hopeful that I've explained it well enough for someone to be able to assist; specifically with either a formula, or an excel doc that I can enter the numbers into to produce a financial answer.
If not recreational then where would you tag this?